# Print a linked list in reverse order: program not outputting anything

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

I am trying to print a linked list in reverse order using recursion.
i.e. :
if i added 1,2,3,4,5 to the linked list , the program should output 5,4,3,2,1.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void Print(struct Node* n)
{
    if(n->next == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    Print(n->next);
    printf("%d",n->data);
    
}

void Insert(struct Node** head_ref,int data)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if((*head_ref)==NULL)
    {
        (*head_ref) = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        struct Node* temp = (*head_ref);
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    Insert(&head,1);
    Insert(&head,2);
    Insert(&head,3);
    Insert(&head,4);
    
    Print(head);
}
```

I have also tried declaring the head pointer as a global variable but still is is not outputting anything. Any help would be appreciated.
Also if you think there something missing in my code or something that i don't understand correctly, if possible please point me to some resources where i can learn the concept.

Thanks

Comment: And what is your problem? You haven't asked a question

Comment: the mentioned program is not outputting anything

Comment: recurse first, print afterwards ... so, the `1` goes something like this: recurse with 2, 3, 4, ... and when recursion ends print `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes:

The loop condition int the loop that finds the last node is wrong.

It is:

```
while(temp!=NULL)
```

while it should be:

```
while(temp->next!=NULL)
```

Otherwise, the update at:

```
while (temp != NULL) { ... }
temp->next = new_node; // segmentation fault
```

will explode because `temp` is `NULL` at that place.

Second error:

When printing the early check if tail is reached should be:

```
if(n == NULL) // not `if (n->next == NULL)`
```

Otherwise, the tail will **not** be printed.

After those fixes the program prints:

```
1234
```

---

If you want to reverse the order just swap `printf` and recursive `Print()` calls:

```
    Print(n->next);
    printf("%d",n->data);
```